# Proper data structure for D3 stacked bar chart

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to visualize this data in a stacked bar chart with D3 v4:

```
var data = [ 
   {'id': '10', 'status': 'on', 'variant': 'A', 'value': '200'},
   {'id': '10', 'status': 'on', 'variant': 'B', 'value': '500'},
   {'id': '11', 'status': 'off', 'variant': 'A', 'value': '100'},
   {'id': '12', 'status': 'on', 'variant': 'A', 'value': '600'},
   ... 
]
```

All elements with the same key `id` should stack on the x axis, where `value` defines the height and `status` defines the color.
A data set may contain multiple elements with the same `id` but different `status` or `variant`, like id=10 in the example.
Which  format would be suitable to stack this data? My approach was nesting it:

```
var nested = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.id; })
  .entries(data);
```

From here I am not sure how to generate the y0 and y1 values.
Can I use [d3.stack](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#_stack)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through the `values` array in each top-level object and keep a running total of `value`, which becomes `y0` for each `<rect>`. `y1` then is `y0 + value`.

Then bind each top-level object to a `<g>` tag representing the entire stack, translate that to the appropriate `x` position (assuming bars are vertical), and append `<rect>`s to each `<g>` with the `values` prop as data. Set the `height` and `y` position of the rect according to where in the stack it belongs. That might look like:

```
var groups = d3.selectAll("g")
   .data(nested)
   .enter().append("g");
groups.attr("transform","translate...");
var rects = groups.selectAll("rect")
   .data(function(d) { return d.values })
   .enter().append("rect");
rects
   .attr("width",...)
   .attr("height",...)
   .attr("y",...)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @anbnyc! With your help I solved the problem. Complete solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/ed8ow9hp/1/